# Jquery Select get array object value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html-select

I'm looking for something that can be iterate easily and fast or the best method for **adding from a JavaScript array object using jQuery**, and **can submit to JavaScript array object using jQuery**?

This is what I did:

```
 var view = [{id:123, name:john, type:5},{id:234, name:adam, type:4},{id:456, name:max, type:3}]

    var dis = $.map(view, function (item) {
       var opt = $('<option/>', { selected:'selected', text: item.name})
       return opt
     });
     $(".select-js-view").append(dis);
```

The Result from Select is :

```
var selectedValues = $('.select-js-view').val();
console.log(selectedValues);

selectedValues = [john,adam]
```

So my question is, how can i get array object values like (view)? or maybe someone could give me a hint on this.

Comment: when you are mapping only `item.name` to `dis` variable and then `dis` to `.select-js-view`, then how you can retrieve full array from `.select-js-view`? you can get maximum `name` only. as `.select-js-view` knows about `name` property only

Comment: ahh.. your mean you need array of object, not array of string. right?

Comment: @DeepakSharma sorry my mistake, yup I want in array of object ..

Comment: below @hassan has already answered it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first: you must put names in `"` sign.

Now, You can try this.

```js
var view = [{id:123, name:"john", type:5},{id:234, name:"adam", type:4},{id:456, name:"max", type:3}]

    var dis = $.map(view, function (item) {
       var opt = $('<option/>', { selected:'selected', text: item.name});
       opt[0].info = item;
       return opt
     });
     $(".select-js-view").append(dis);
     
     $(".select-js-view").change(function(){
         console.log($(this.options).filter(":selected")[0].info);
     });
     
     //If you want to get all (similar view var):
     function GetAll(){
        var r=[];
        $(".select-js-view option").each(function(i, o){
            r.push(o.info);
        });
        return r;
     }
     console.log(GetAll());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b style='color: #090'>change me:</b> 
<select class="select-js-view"></select>
```